# Thymeleaf - passing object to another field without redirecting

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying get this object (p) of this object list from controller when the user click in  [this a href](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qHdW.png) :

```
                 <li th:each="p : ${products}">
                  <figure>
                    <a class="aa-product-img" href="#"><img th:src="${p.picture1min}" style="width: 250px; height: 300px;"></a>
                    <a class="aa-add-card-btn"href="#"><span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>Add To Cart</a>
                     <figcaption>
                      <h4 class="aa-product-title"><a href="#" th:text="${p.nome}">Polo T-Shirt</a></h4>
                      <span class="aa-product-price" th:text="${'R$: ' + #numbers.formatDecimal(p.newPrice, 0, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}"></span><span th:if="${p.isVaryingColor()}" class="aa-product-price"><del th:text="${'R$: ' + #numbers.formatDecimal(p.oldPrice, 0, 'POINT', 2, 'COMMA')}"></del></span>
                    </figcaption>
                  </figure>                     
                  <div class="aa-product-hvr-content">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add to Cart"><span class="fa fa-heart-o"></span></a>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle2="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Espiar" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#quick-view-modal"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></a>                            
                  </div>
                  <!-- product badge -->
                  <span class="aa-badge aa-sale" href="#"  th:if="${p.isVaryingColor()}">Promotion!</span>
                </li>
```

and send to this [Quick view product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xiUA.png) (pop-up div) on this same page

```
 <!-- Modal view content -->
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="aa-product-view-content">
                            <h3>T-Shirt</h3>
                            <div class="aa-price-block">
                              <span class="aa-product-view-price" th:text="${product.price}">$34.99</span>
                              <p class="aa-product-avilability">Avilability: <span>In stock</span></p>
                            </div>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis animi, veritatis quae repudiandae quod nulla porro quidem, itaque quis quaerat!</p>
                            <h4>Size</h4>
                            <div class="aa-prod-view-size">
                              <a href="#">S</a>
                              <a href="#">M</a>
                              <a href="#">L</a>
                              <a href="#">XL</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="aa-prod-quantity">
                              <input type="text" value="1" th:value="${product.quantity}">
                              <p class="aa-prod-category">
                                Category: <a href="#">Polo T-Shirt</a>
                              </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="aa-prod-view-bottom">
                              <a href="#" class="aa-add-to-cart-btn"><span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>Add To Cart</a>
                              <a href="#" class="aa-add-to-cart-btn">View Details</a>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

showing information about this object (product) but I don't want to redirect the page, maybe there is a way to send this object to the controller, search the database and return the product for quick modal viewing without redirecting the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using Ajax, when the user clicks the button, ajax sends the product id as a parameter to a method in the controller and returns to the thymeleaft page and ajax updates these fields